# Help with OpenGL ES -- Improving PanoramaGL's spherical resolution?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, 3d, panoramas

I started playing around with [PanoramaGL](http://code.google.com/p/panoramagl/) the other night. After finagling with the downloaded project (there were some minor issues that prevented it from compiling right out the gate), I got it to work -- I loaded up a 1200 by 512(ish) panorama image and got the spherical view working pretty well. Two problems: I'm loading too large of a texture, which makes this work only on an iPhone4 (at least, I think that's why it didn't work on my iPad), and the panorama turned out to be pretty blurry.

I started doing a bit of studying on doing 3D on the iPhone and I'm not (too) embarrassed to admit that most of the concepts are over my head. I don't have any experience working with 3D and I'm hoping to get some help from the good folks here at StackOverflow.

Here's what I want to do: I want to break up my panorama image into tiles (I was thinking vertical strips but I'm open to doing it in other ways). I want to load these tiles as textures on the `PLSphere` view and tell it that a certain tile corresponds to certain angles.

Looking at the source of `PanoramaGL`, it looks like there'd be a good place to put this code in. In the `PLSphere` class, there's this block of code:

```
- (void)internalRender
{
    gluQuadricNormals(quadratic, GLU_SMOOTH);
    gluQuadricTexture(quadratic, true);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ((PLTexture *)[textures objectAtIndex:0]).textureId);

    gluSphere(quadratic, kRatio, divs, divs);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

And looking at `PLCube`, I see the following code in its `internalRender` method:

```
// Front Face
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ((PLTexture *)[textures objectAtIndex:kCubeFrontFaceIndex]).textureId);
glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Based on this, I would think that I could specify a direction (using something like `glNormal3f`) and bind a tile as a texture.

Am I on the right track here? I'm hopeful someone can provide me with guidance to get this to work.

Thanks!

Comment: couldn't you just convert your spherical panorama to a cubic panorama ? This would give you 6 smaller textures instead of 1 big. This would help you getting over the maximum hardware texture size.

Comment: Unfortunately, the panorama images that I'm using are spherical. Unless there was an easy way to change them to cubic, I'm stuck trying to figure out how to get this to perform well with the spherical mode. Though.. hmm.. maybe I will look into what it takes to change it to cubic..

Answer (score 2):

You can change speherical to 6 cube textures using hugin/pano
see

http://vinayhacks.blogspot.com/2010/11/converting-equirectangular-panorama-to.html

dont texture sizes have to be powers of 2?

Comment: How to use it, if it is for Ubuntu linux, not OSX?